How can I add data to a geometry column in supabase using SQLalchemy?
I have the following table in supabase where I have the postgis extension installed:
create table
  public.prueba (
    id smallint generated by default as identity not null,
    name text null,
    age smallint null,
    created_at timestamp without time zone null,
    punto geography null,
    constraint prueba_pkey primary key (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;

which relates to this SQLalchemy class:
class Prueba(Base):
    __tablename__ = "prueba"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        sa.SmallInteger, sa.Identity(start=1), primary_key=True
    )
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(sa.String(50), nullable=False)
    age: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(sa.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    punto: Mapped[WKBElement] = mapped_column(
        Geometry(geometry_type="POINT", srid=4326, spatial_index=True)
    )

I use geoalchemy2 as suggested by this question but everytime I try to add data to this table the code fails.
The code I use to add data is the following:
prueba = Prueba(
    name="Prueba_2",
    age=5,
    created_at=datetime.now(),
    punto="POINT(-1.0 1.0)",
)

with Session() as session:
    session.add(prueba)
    session.commit()

I create add the data this way because I was following the geoalchemy2 orm tutorial but when I run I get this exception:
  File "c:...\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 941, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) function st_geomfromewkt(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: ...a_2', 5, '2024-12-28T18:49:07.130429'::timestamp, ST_GeomFro...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

[SQL: INSERT INTO prueba (name, age, created_at, punto) VALUES (%(name)s, %(age)s, %(created_at)s, ST_GeomFromEWKT(%(punto)s)) RETURNING prueba.id]
[parameters: {'name': 'Prueba_2', 'age': 5, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 12, 28, 18, 49, 7, 130429), 'punto': 'POINT(-1.0 1.0)'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)

I guess that the error is in the way I have defined the class because the same error appears when I leave the punto value empty.
Also I have tried using a similar approach as this tutorial and tring to add the data with this code:
punto=WKBElement("POINT(10 25)", srid=4326),

gives me a different error:
 File "c:\...\back\main.py", line 16, in main
    punto=WKBElement("POINT(10 25)", srid=4326),
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\...\.venv\Lib\site-packages\geoalchemy2\elements.py", line 201, in __init__
    header = binascii.unhexlify(data[:18])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
binascii.Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found

